# How to navigate to other chrome windows while my vba code works on one chrome window

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, search, minimize

I have a vba code to automate search and code is as follows.

```
**Sub chrome()
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Excel.Application.Selection
obj.Start "chrome", ""
For Each element In myArray
obj.Get "url here"
obj.FindElementByName("q").SendKeys (element)
obj.FindElementById("start-search").Click
Application.SendKeys ("^t")
obj.SwitchToNextWindow
Next element
Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub**
```

The issue is that the chrome is very slow while the macro running. Its loading each tab one by one and once the tab completes loading the other tab opens. It makes my process slow. I'm creating this macro to minimize the time but it seems taking a very long time. I cannot work on headless chrome window as I need the window after all the tabs loaded.
I have tried made the chrome window work on the background so I can work on another chrome window till my macro runs, but as soon as I navigate to the new chrome window the vba code shows error as "nosuchwindowerror" "window not found".
I looking for a solution where I can open the search tabs very immediately the previous tab starts loading and to not wait until it loads completely. Or else I can make my chrome window opened through vb code to work on the background and so that I can work on another window in foreground.

Comment: Some of your code, for the block shown, is missing. Have you tried spawning generating webdriver instances in a loop and setting in variables? Bit of a pain but ok for small numbers. Do you need javascript to load on those pages? Have you checked whether you can do the achieve the same final result by xmlhttp request? Some of this may be outside your control - i.e. website related.

Comment: I'm totally new to coding. I have declared the webriver instance globally as                
Dim obj As New ChromeDriver. I am creating an excel macro where i assigned the above code to a button. the code is actually working opening a tab and searching the text fetched from excel. but I couldn't work on any other window and its showing as Nosuchwindowerror. Is there any way to get session id of the chrome window opened through my vb code. And so that I can use that to stick with the same browser until my macro gets completed.

Comment: There are several ways of controlling /tracking different windows. See [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+window+handles&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB865GB865&oq=selenium+window+handles&aqs=chrome..69i57.4335j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If you have an early bound webdriver instance i.e. you used New Webdriver then you should be able to see which methods selenium basic has access to. I think it does window handles and definitely does SwitchTo methods. IIRC there is another method currently escaping me I will see if I can look up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I found another way to minimize the time and I'm again stuck in some point and I have posted the question in the same. Kindly have a look to help me if you can. Once again thanks for your response. Kindly use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640111/getting-error-while-using-a-script-in-vba if you wish to help.