# Getting error while using a script in VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, google-chrome, url, runtime-error

```
**Public Sub WebTest()
    Dim keys As New keys, arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim temp1(), temp2() As String
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<==Adjust to your sheet
    arr = Application.Transpose(Selection) '<== Adjust to your range
    With bot
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "url here"
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
                If i > 1 Then
                    .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "url here"
                    .SwitchToNextWindow
                End If
                .FindElementByCss("[name=q]").SendKeys arr(i)
                .SendKeys bot.keys.Enter
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub**
```

I'm using the above code to fetch values from excel and search in a particular url.
While executing its loading two searches and after that its showing an error as **"run-time error 17 javascript error illegal invocation"** I don't know what I'm missing in the code or which I need to alter.

Comment: Is there a test url?

Comment: https://www.gandhi.com.mx/ this is the url i'm using..

Comment: And  arr() contains your search terms?

Comment: yes exactly. I fetch them from the excel.